How to get search results in eclipse rcp
I have created a custom view, now i want to show the search results in this view.
In eclipse when we search any text it is displayed in search view, i am not able to find where this search result is created and stored in the eclipse.
How can I perform search for any text and show it in this custom view

Plain text search is in the org.eclipse.search plugin along with the NewSearchUI code, other searches are in the plug-ins that contribute the search page.

how can i get the search result
if I use NewSearchUI it is showing results in search tab only
but i want search results so that i can display it in my custom tab

The search code is not designed to do that, so there is not going to be a simple way.

By tab you mean view, right? If yes, please edit your question to use the correct term. Showing the search results in a custom view and not in the Search view sounds like a pretty bad idea. Why you want to do this? Are you aware of the org.eclipse.search.searchPages and org.eclipse.search.searchResultViewPages extension points?

can i use org.eclipse.ui.views to create a new view and show search results in the view

No, as we have told you repeatedly the search code only displays results in pages in its own view.
